# Load related data in one many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have two entities `Session` and `Student`, and a join entity `StudentSessions`.

Now i have a Profile Screen which needs to query all data of the Selected Student.

> Student.cs

```
public class Student
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
    public DateTime ChildDOB { get; set; }
    public DateTime AdmissionDate { get; set; }
    /* removed for brewity*/

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public Lead Source { get; set; }
    public Session CurrentSession
    {
        get
        {
            return (StudentSessions != null && StudentSessions.Any(x => x.Session.IsCurrentlyRunning))
                ? StudentSessions.First(x => x.Session.IsCurrentlyRunning).Session : null;
        }
    }

    public List<StudentSession> StudentSessions { get; set; }
}
```

> Session.cs

```
public class Session
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime SessionStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime SessionEnd { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public bool IsCurrentlyRunning { get { return SessionEnd == null || SessionEnd > DateTime.UtcNow; } }

    public Teacher AssignedTeacher { get; set; }
    public List<Staff> AssignedStaff { get; set; }
    public List<StudentSession> StudentSessions { get; set; }
}
```

> StudentSession.cs

```
public class StudentSession
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long StudentID { get; set; }
    public long SessionID { get; set; }

    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public Session Session { get; set; }

    public List<SessionTerm> SessionTerms { get; set; }
}
```

> StudentController.cs

```
public class StudentController : Controller
{
    MasterContext db;

    public StudentController(MasterContext dbcontext) { db = dbcontext; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromRoute]long ID, [FromQuery]string view, [FromQuery]int page)
    {
        IQueryable<Student> studentqry;
        switch (view)
        {
            case "ListAll":
                studentqry = from s in db.Students select s;
                return View(viewName: view, model: await studentqry.OrderByDescending(x => x.AdmissionDate).Skip(page * 50).Take(50).ToListAsync());
            case "Create":
            case "Profile":
                studentqry = (from s in db.Students where s.ID == ID select s)
                    .Include(x => x.Source).ThenInclude(x=>x.Interactions)
                    .Include(x => x.StudentSessions);
                return View(viewName: view, model: await studentqry.SingleAsync());
            case "Edit":
            case "EditInteraction":
            case "ListInteractions":
            default: return View(viewName: "Default");
        }
    }
}
```

Since StudentSessions in Student is having a one-many relationship, i cannot load the related Session data using ThenInclude in StudentSessions for all StudentSessions of Student.

I have tried reading docs and searching on google but due the fact that Entity-Framework Core is relatively new, not much help is available at the moment. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `.Include(x => x.StudentSessions).ThenInclude(x => x.Session);`? The core of your problem is not really clear to me.

Comment: @grek40 there is no .ThenInclude(x => x.Session) i have updated the question accordingly

Comment: This should actually work for collections, so your problem may be something else.

Comment: @grek40 x.StudentSessions is a List and not a single value so you cannot directly use its navigation properties

Comment: EntityFrameworkQueryableExtension has multiple overloads of `ThenInclude`. One of them is `public static IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TProperty> ThenInclude<TEntity, TPreviousProperty, TProperty>(this IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, ICollection<TPreviousProperty>> source, Expression<Func<TPreviousProperty, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath) where TEntity : class;` Intellisense however, had its problems to identify this until I finished writing the statement (VS 2013)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with Visual Studio Intellisense, writing the navigation property, compiled and worked perfectly.

```
.Include(x => x.StudentSessions).ThenInclude(x => x.Session)
```

Comment: spent 2 hours cause of this thanks for adding the answer.